# Change Bootstrsp 4 Active Pills Background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav, nav-pills

I was trying to find the answer to my question.

No one really had what i was looking for. All they could was change the background color when the nav pill was focused.

So what i did was open the bootstrap 4 CSS file and found my own answer.

So for anyone looking to use bootstrap 4 nav pills and want to change the background color.

Please use the following code

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
color: #fff;
background-color: #007bff;
}
```

this will allow you to change the background color of active nav pills.

I hope this helps a lot of people as I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to find the answer to my question.

No one really had what i was looking for. All they could was change the background color when the nav pill was focused.

So what i did was open the bootstrap 4 CSS file and found my own answer.

So for anyone looking to use bootstrap 4 nav pills and want to change the background color.

Please use the following code

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
color: #fff;
background-color: #007bff;
}
```

this will allow you to change the background color of active nav pills.

I hope this helps a lot of people as I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere.

Comment: You could answer yourself before posting as it's only an inspecting->copy selector -> edit/override... :V